# Capturing an image every determined seconds

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to create a program to capture an image every five seconds. This is my source code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
Mat frame;
VideoCapture cap;

cap.open(0);

while(1)
{
    cap>>frame;
    imshow("frame",frame);

    if(waitKey(10)=='c')
    {
        QString nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(QString::number(x));
        imwrite(nama.toStdString(),frame);
        x++;

        sleep(5);

        nama = QString("webcam_capture_%1.jpg") .arg(QString::number(x));
        imwrite(nama.toStdString(),frame);
        x++;
     }
    else if(waitKey(10)=='x')
        break;
}

cap.release();

return a.exec();
}
```

The program supposed to captured two images when I press 'c', when the sleep executed, the program freezes for five seconds and then continue. But the image result between the first capture and the second capture are same.

What is the correct function to delay the program? Why the image capture result is same between two photos?

I'm using Windows 7, Qtcreator 2.7.2 Qt5, openCV 2.4.6. I planned to run this program on Linux too.

**EDIT:**

SOLVED! After adding the first `cap>>frame` as stated by Ove, I added one more `cap>>frame` and the next image capture is really the image after 5 seconds. The number of `cap>>frame` needed depends on your cpu speed. I tried it on mini PC and I needed five `cap>>frame`

Comment: you are using Qt but no the proper event loop? make a QObject and use one of the timer capabilities

Comment: I tried using QTimer. like `QTimer timer` and `timer.start(1000)` the result is same.

Comment: Please eliminate the blocking sleep. that is just wrong. You will block the for 5 seconds every time!

Comment: I tried deleting the sleep function and the result is the same. Why can't I use sleep for delaying? Then what is the right function to delay the capture for five seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading the frame once at the start of the loop and then you are writing the same image to two different files. That's why you get the same image.

After the call to `sleep(5)`, you should add this line:

```
cap>>frame;
```

in order to capture a new image and write the second image to the second file.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! The saved image is now different, but the time gap between 1st capture and 2nd capture is not five seconds but very short. How can I fix this?

Comment: What `sleep` function are you using? Look at its documentation. Is the parameter to `sleep` in seconds or milliseconds (or something else)? If it's in milliseconds, you should use `sleep(5000)`.

Comment: I'm using sleep function from #include <unistd.h> and base on this [link] (http://brickos.sourceforge.net/docs/APIs/html-c/unistd_8h.html) it should be on seconds

Comment: It looks like `sleep` can sometimes return sooner if a signal arrives [see the sleep documentation](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_445.html). Check the return value of sleep to see how many seconds it actually slept. Maybe you should try using a different sleep function (maybe `QThread::sleep ( unsigned long secs )` )